# Where is the warped throat in Klebanov-Strassler geometry?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, differential-geometry, string-theory, curvature

In string theory, it is common to work in the Klebanov-Strassler geometry to find AdS and dS vacua. Applications are that anti-branes can be placed at the tip of this deformed/warped conifold to obtain a positive contribution to the overall scalar potential.

However, I am wondering where this deformed conifold actually is? Is the idea that this is the shape of the entire universe? If so, does anyone have any idea where we are in this warped throat? [image]

Also, what causes the warping in this picture?